# Probabilistic optimization problem on tree vertex selection without replacement proportional to the degree

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, graph-theory, stochastic-processes, combinatorial-optimization

We are given a tree $T(V,E)$ with $|V|=n$ vertices, where $V=\{v_1,v_2,\ldots, v_n\}$. We denote by $d_i$ the degree of vertex $v_i$ for all $i\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$.
In a sequential fashion, we select *without replacement* $q<n$ vertices from $V$, one by one, with a probability linearly proportional to each vertex degree, viz., at each time step $t\in\{1,2,\ldots, q\}$ we select $v_i$ with probability
$\frac{d_i}{\sum_{j\in I_t} d_j}$ where set $I_t$ contains the indices of all vertices that have not been selected yet up to time $t$.

Finally, let $m$ a given integer such that $q+m\le n$ and let $s$ be the sum of the largest $m$ degrees of the $n-q$ vertices of $V$ that have not been selected after the whole process.

---

**Question:**  What is the asymptotic maximum expected value $s^*$ of $s$ over all trees $T(V,E)$, expressed as a function of $n$, $q$ and $m$ - when $n,q,m\to\infty$ and $q,m\in o(n)$?

*Can we find at least an asymptotically significant upper bound for the maximum expected value of $s^*$?*

---

---

***Note:*** I think the following method can provide an approximation of the solution, but it is not clear to me how tight it is. First of all, for the sake of simplicity, assume that the sum of all degrees is equal to $2n$ instead of $2(n-1)$, to obtain a simpler calculation for this approximation for $n\gg 1$. We could have $z$ (to be determined) degrees all equal to $\frac{n}{z}+1$, and $n-z$ degrees all equal to $1$. To determine $z$ our goal is to have that the number of vertices with high degrees equals the sum of $m$ and the expected number of high degree vertices selected. This way, all $m$ vertices will be part (in expectation) of the high degrees vertices. Hence it is sufficient to solve the equation $z=m+\mathbb{E}\left[\mathrm{WalleniusHypergeometricDistribution}(q,z,n,n/z+1)\right]$ w.r.t. $z$, to obtain the approximatation $s^*\approx m\left(\frac{n}{z}+1\right)$.

*As I wrote above, I am wondering whether this degree allocation method yields an asymptotically optimal solution as required in the question, for $n,q,m\to\infty$ while $q,m\in o(n)$.*

Comment: My initial conjecture was that we want to pack the "weight" (which is to say, the surplus $n$ above the minimum of one element per set) evenly into $m+q$ sets so that we're guaranteed $s \ge m + \frac{m}{m+q}\lfloor \frac{n}{m+q} \rfloor$, but this turns out to be suboptimal in many cases. When $m+q = n$ we want to split the weight evenly (so $|S_i| = 2$), and when $n \gg m+q$ it seems that we want to split it evenly between $m$ sets, but in between there are some interestingly skewed optimal distributions.

Comment: Thank you @PeterTaylor . I was thinking that a good candidate solution would have been splitting the $n$ "mobile" items evenly into $m+q$ sets. Could you please clarify why this approach does not work when $n\gg m+q$, in both cases $m\gg q$ and $q \gg m$?

Comment: BTW, I rephrased the whole problem from a graph perspective. Now the sum of all cardinalities is the sum of all vertex degrees, which is always equal to $2(n-1)$ (instead of $2n$, but it is a minor change).

Comment: I seem to have misread my [empirical results](https://gist.github.com/pjt33/80048c8b2c6995096b8a1654a1c205f8). It's certainly the case that the distribution isn't a rounded step function, but I retract the claim about $n \gg m+q$.

Comment: That's very interesting @PeterTaylor , thank you! At the moment, the only pattern I see is that, in the general case $q+m<n$, the first $1$ (in the decreasing order) is at the $(q+m+1)$-th or $(q+m)$-th position.

Comment: Drawing inspiration from your first approach @PeterTaylor, I  just added a note to the text problem with my approximated solution. Please, let me know what is your opinion about it. Thank you.

Comment: That's a nice refinement. I've tried finding exact solutions for small $m+q$ under the simplifying assumption that $n > 2q+m$. $q=m=1$ has $s^* \approx \frac9{16}n$; more precisely, if the "excess" weight is $w$ we distribute it as $\frac{n+2w-2}{4}$ to one set and $\frac{2w-n+2}{4}$ to another for $s = \frac{(n+2w+2)^2}{8(n+w)}$. Clearly we want $2w \ge n-2$ for this to be sensible. With $q=1, m=2$ we get $(\frac{n+2w-3}6)^2 (\frac{w-n+3}3) 1^{n-3}$ giving $s = \frac{(n^2+4wn+4w^2-6n+9)}{6(n+w)}$ if $w \ge n - 3$. But if we continue this to $q=1, m=3$ we require $2w \ge 3n-12$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @PeterTaylor . Is $\frac{2w-n+2}{4}$ potentially negative in general, for $q=m=1$? BTW, I understand your point. Actually for the problem I am trying to solve, an asymptotic solution for $n,q,m\to\infty$, with $q,m\in \mathcal{o}(n)$ would be sufficient. Maybe we can at least find this asymptotic solution.

Comment: The potential for it to be negative is why I say that "we want $2w \ge n-2$ for this to be sensible".

Comment: I see, thank you @PeterTaylor

Comment: I have been working on a similar problem and maybe some of the results I stumbled upon would interest you. Baring some restrictions on the degree sequences, in my case, i could actually use iterations with replacement (which is very useful for having closed formulas and assymptotic solutions). Optimal solutions also are hard because of various reasons but mainly because $d_i$ is varying in my case.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback @RiezFrechetKolmogorov . In my problem here for any $i\in\{1,2,\ldots, n\}$, $d_i$ can be any positive integer as long as $\sum_{i=1}^n d_i=2(n-1)\sim 2n$ for $n\to\infty$, but each $d_i$ is fixed. What kind of restrictions on the degree sequences are you referring? Could you please provide some references? By the way, asymptotic results (*even tight upper bound*) are sufficient for me.